# dplyr: Groupwise subtraction of values (based on pre-filtered rows)

Tags: r, filter, group-by, dplyr

I'm stuck on a (probably) very obvious thing but I can't figure out what the actual problem is.

```
DF <- data.frame(Gene = c(rep("A",8), rep("X",8)),
             Genotype = c(rep("WT",4),rep("mut",4),rep("WT",4),rep("mut",4)),
             TimePoint = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
             Value = c(12.5,12.33,11,10,23.22,22,21.2,45.3,22,12,23,21.2,23.2,45.3,21,22))
```

What I want to do: 
Subtract the value corresponding to TimePoint == 1 from all values within a group (here: Group = Gene, Genotype).

I would like to have the output as shown as result of this code here:

```
DF %>% group_by(Gene, Genotype) %>% mutate(Diff = Value - first(Value))
```

However, instead of first-function I would choose value based on a given TimePoint that does not necessarily has to be the first in each group.

My idea was to do something like this, but actually it does not use the grouped data as expected:

```
DF %>% group_by(Gene, Genotype) %>% mutate(Diff = Value - filter(.,TimePoint == 1)$Value)
```

I really don't know why the grouped data isn't piped correctly to the filter statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the grouping step, subset the 'Value' by creating a logical vector with 'TimePoint' i.e. `TimePoint == 1` and subtract it from 'Value'

```
DF %>%
   group_by(Gene, Genotype) %>%
   mutate((Diff = Value - Value[TimePoint == 1]))
```

---

Or another option is `match` to get the index

```
DF %>%
   group_by(Gene, Genotype) %>% 
   mutate((Diff = Value - Value[match(1, TimePoint)]))
```

---

If we really need to use `filter`, then filter the dataset, then do a `right_join` and get the difference

```
DF %>%
   filter(TimePoint == 1) %>% 
   select(Gene, Genotype, Value1 = Value)  %>% 
   right_join(DF) %>% 
   mutate(Diff = Value - Value1) %>%
   select(-Value1)
```

---

In the OP's way of `filter`ing the extracted 'Value' after the `filter` are not following the `group_by` constraint and it is only subtracting by recycling

Comment: Thank you very much :)
Is there a way I can use 'filter' in this case instead of 'base'-Syntax. My main issue was also to understand why 'filter' does not work here

Comment: @interrobang  One of the main attractions of pipe is to make the flow more easier to read.  By nesting multiple functions within a pipe makes it difficult to read

Comment: @count That is already in the OP's post.  I think OP wanted to do some `filter`ing based on the 'TimePoint'